# How to use system("start E:\myprogram.exe")

Tags: c++, path, system

I want to open my other program with:

```
system("start");
```

The program is on: `E:\Pasd\swe\Dtr`.
Program name: `app.exe`
What should i type into " " to run. I try:

```
 system("start E:\Pasd\swe\Dtr\app.exe");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes so the compiler doesn't think there special characters so `"E:\Pasd\swe\Dtr\app.exe"` would become `"E:\\Pasd\\swe\\Dtr\\app.exe"`

Comment: Gah, didn't re-read my comment, and now I can't edit it. Apparently even in SO, backslash is used as an escape character... Meant to say something similar to Corvin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
system("start E:\\Pasd\\swe\\Dtr\\app.exe");
```